# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE' when updating table using SQLMetal generated class

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, sqlmetal

I have a pretty basic table in SQL Server (dual key, no foreign keys). I have generated mapping code using SQLMetal. I have also extended the auto generated partial class so I can implement IEquatable. The problem is that once I implement IEquatable, I lose the ability to update records using my SQLMetal generated classes. When submitting changes I get the following exception:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

The sample code below illustrates the problem. It runs fine until implementing IEquatable:

```
var connection = "Your connection string";
var dbInsert = new DBTest(connection);
var recordToInsert = new TestTable()
{
    PrimaryKey1 = 123,
    PrimaryKey2 = "Red",
    TheValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
};
dbInsert.TestTable.InsertOnSubmit(recordToInsert);
dbInsert.SubmitChanges();

var dbEdit = new DBTest(connection);
dbEdit.Log = Console.Out;
var ti1 = dbEdit.TestTable.Single(x => x.PrimaryKey1 == 123 && x.PrimaryKey2 == "Red");
ti1.TheValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
dbEdit.SubmitChanges();
```

This is my implementation for IEquatable (auto generated by ReSharper):

```
public partial class TestTable : IEquatable<TestTable>
{
    public bool Equals(TestTable other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return _PrimaryKey1 == other._PrimaryKey1 && string.Equals(_PrimaryKey2, other._PrimaryKey2) && string.Equals(_TheValue, other._TheValue);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((TestTable)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = _PrimaryKey1;
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (_PrimaryKey2 != null ? _PrimaryKey2.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (_TheValue != null ? _TheValue.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at the query that prints out in the output window. When IEquatable is implemented, the SET clause is empty (and causes the exception to be thrown):

> UPDATE [dbo].[TestTable]
>   SET
>   WHERE ([PrimaryKey1] = @p0) AND ([PrimaryKey2] = @p1) AND ([TheValue] = @p2)
>   -- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [123]
>   -- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Red]
>   -- @p2: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [8dedfdca-84e9-4b7a-9268-4bbdde2e9ad2]

Here is the same output without IEquatable implemented:

> UPDATE [dbo].[TestTable]
>   SET [TheValue] = @p3
>   WHERE ([PrimaryKey1] = @p0) AND ([PrimaryKey2] = @p1) AND ([TheValue] = @p2)
>   -- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [123]
>   -- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Red]
>   -- @p2: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [8f6e72ee-f89e-40f3-830f-18e8b4b40f9e]
>   -- @p3: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1ecaff9d-d460-4f3e-b35d-138ddeb2fb63]

Is this behavior expected? Is there a way to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that overriding the GetHashCode() method messes with the DataContext's ability to track changes. Removing the GetHashCode override resolved the issue.